# AppiumLibrary for Robot Framework - Getting A Button's Text

Tags: appium, robotframework, appium-android

I am experimenting with AppiumLibrary in RobotFramework and have a simple test for a requirement that states:  "the Set button should exist on this page.".  I am testing this by retrieving the button that has a specified ID and then checking if that button has the right text.

I am able to retrieve the button I want via ID however am having trouble getting the actual text on the button.

Here is how the button is defined on the web page:

```
<button id="button-set" class="button ng-binding" style="width: 20%">Set</button>
```

Very simple!  Using Appium Desktop in web/hybrid app mode and clicking on the Set button it says the "text" attribute shows "Set".  However I've learned that using the attributes in Appium Desktop arent valid when searching for elements on a webpage, for example searching by the Class attribute in Appium Desktop (android.widget.Button) is not correct because on the web page the class for the button is instead:  "button ng-binding".

I have tried the following:

```
# this retrieves the button fine, by ID
PAGE SHOULD CONTAIN ELEMENT         xpath=//button[@id="button-set"]
# these all return 'None'
${name}=  GET ELEMENT ATTRIBUTE     xpath=//button[@id="button-set"]    name
${text}=  GET ELEMENT ATTRIBUTE     xpath=//button[@id="button-Set"]    text
```

So, I am unsure which Attribute to use to retrieve the text when retrieving element by ID.  Instead, I have tried to retrieve the element this way:

```
# this also passes fine - I feel like I should also make sure this button has the correct ID, to make the mapping
# between test procedures and cases easier, but if this is as good as it gets then
# this can be argued for
PAGE SHOULD CONTAIN ELEMENT         xpath=//button[contains(text(),'set')]

# however, the following does not make sense, this returns "button" instead of "button-set", which makes me think the xpath query is not correct
${id2}=    GET ELEMENT ATTRIBUTE    xpath=//button[contains(text(),'set')]    id
# again, both of these return 'None'
${name2}=  GET ELEMENT ATTRIBUTE    xpath=//button[contains(text(),'set')]    name
${text2}=  GET ELEMENT ATTRIBUTE    xpath=//button[contains(text(),'set')]    text
```

I have also tried the following:

```
${element}=   GET WEBELEMENT        xpath=//button[@id="button-set"]
# this returns "button-set" as you'd expect:
${id3}=          GET ELEMENT ATTRIBUTE    ${element}      id
# these again return 'None'
${name3}=        GET ELEMENT ATTRIBUTE    ${element}      name
${text3}=        GET ELEMENT ATTRIBUTE    ${element}      text
```

I feel like this should be a very simple thing to do, and can see in other questions that you would use the Name attribute when using pure Appium.  However, using the Robot Framework library instead, that these doesn't appear to be the right approach.  I must be doing something pretty simple wrong here, can anyone point it out?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Stumbling across the same issue when trying to fetch element's attributes via Get Element Attribute keyword. It seems that when fetching **for the element's text, your best bet is to use Get Text keyword.** Switching to Get Text keyword solved the problem on my case. Please see the links below for further details. **Spoiler**: there aren't any real explanations as to why the Get Element Attribute is flaky.

- https://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html#Get%20Text
- https://github.com/serhatbolsu/robotframework-appiumlibrary/issues/98